# How to print ${STR1} and $STR2 - not their contents - into a file?

Tags: shell-script, echo, printf

I need to print expressions `${STR1}` and `$STR2` into a file -- not the content of the variables. How can I accomplish this using echo or printf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to escape the `$` character, as in

```
echo "\${STR1}" >> myfile
```

or

```
echo "\$STR2" >> myfile
```

Alternatively, you can use single quotes

```
echo '${STR1}' '$STR2'
```